# Django management command not found by cron

Tags: linux, django

I made a management app imaginitively called `update`. The following work fine from the command line:

```
./manage.py update
/full/path/manage.py update
```

But when I have the following cron command:

```
00 */3 * * * /websites/bnc/manage.py update >/dev/null
```

It emails me this error:

> Unknown command: 'update'
>
> Type 'manage.py help' for usage.

It smells like a path issue but I can't see how because I can call it manually from wherever. Any idea what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environment is likely not the same, so PYTHONPATH/PATH are not set. It might fail to find import django (or python/lib/site-packages).

Comment: How do I find the PYTHONPATH of my user? I tried `echo $PYTHONPATH` but it returned a blank line.

Comment: You can figure out where python/django is from python interactive prompt: >>> import django  >>> print django.__file__ . That ought to give you a hint. Not sure on the details of cron and PYTHONPATH setup though. Perhaps write a small script that sets up env then runs manage.py update, instead of running it directly. You can test your script with the 'env' command, IIRC.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact problem and found the solution, you need to be int he correct directory to run the Django management commands.

For your example, you'll need to update your crontab like so:

```
00 */3 * * * cd /websites/bnc && ./manage.py update >/dev/null
```

Works like a charm. I'm not sure why, but adding this directory to my PYTHONPATH inside the command didn't work for me, but the above worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing something similar.  Try prefacing `/websites/bnc/manage.py` in your crontab with a `PYTHONPATH=...`

Comment: How do I find the PYTHONPATH of my user? I tried echo $PYTHONPATH but it returned a blank line.